# A problem about ideals and isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $Q[x]$, where $I=(f \in Q[x],f(a)=0)$ and $J=(f \in Q[x],f(b)=0)$. Suppose $a\ne b$ and a,b are in Q. How do I show from $(I+J)/J \to I/(I \cap J)$ is an isomorphism?

I think first I need to define a homomorphism, but I can't find it

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's $Q$? There's something unclear.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @Code-Guru a,b are rational numbers

Comment: @egreg I have changed the problem

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is any ring and $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $R$, then there is a well defined map
$$
f\colon I\to (I+J)/J
$$
which is a group homomorphism. The map is defined by
$$
f(x)=x+J.
$$
The kernel of $f$ is
$$
\ker f=\{x\in I:x+J=J\}=\{x\in I:x\in J\}=I\cap J
$$
and clearly $f$ is surjective. Therefore $f$ induces a (group) isomorphism
$$
\tilde{f}\colon \frac{I}{I\cap J}\to \frac{I+J}{J}
$$
It's very easy to show that $\tilde{f}$ preserves also multiplication.

What's $R$ and what are $I$ and $J$ is completely irrelevant, so long as $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $R$.